# SpriteKit background not fitting to screen on iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iphone-6-plus

I am using a scale mode fill to load a scene with a background with size of 640x1136 as follows:

```
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;

MainMenu *scene = [MainMenu sceneWithSize: self.view.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

[skView presentScene:scene];
```

I am then loading the background inside the screen:

```
    SKSpriteNode *menuBg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"mainBg"];
    menuBg.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    menuBg.position = CGPointZero;
    [self addChild:menuBg];
```

And I expected the backgorund to fill the screen, however it won't resize to fill the screen. I am only holding a @2x background image - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: unless you specify otherwise, the sprite kit view doesn't take up the whole screen

Answer (score 2):

You are not positioning the node in the center of the scene and therefore it won't be scaled correctly with the Aspect Fill scalemode.

Try this instead:

```
menuBg.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
menuBg.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
```

It will set the anchor to the center of your node, and position the node in the center of the scene.